# Searching for the newest file in a specific google drive folder

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm fairly new to coding in javascript and I'm trying to write a script which finds the latest csv file in a folder in google drive, and copies the contents to an existing sheet below the last row of data.

I am getting an error which states the following:

TypeError: Cannot find function hasNext in object Fri May 10 2019 16:42:55 GMT+1000 (AEST). (line 11, file "Code")

Any help would be much appreciated!

CODE:

```
   function getCSV() {
var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById('1mwVqOXikSBh4mcr4iowzJTa4ZvNnzO12'); //       reports_folder_id = id of folder where csv reports are saved
var fi = fSource.getFilesByType('text/csv');// latest       report file

  let lastUpdatedFile = null;
while(fi.hasNext()){
 if(!lastUpdatedFile){ //Checks if we didn't assign anything to lastUpdatedFile
   lastUpdatedFile = fi.next();
 }else{
  var currentFile = fi.next();
  //lastUpdatedFile is older than the current file
  //set lastUpdatedFile to the current file
  if(lastUpdatedFile.getLastUpdated() < currentFile.getLastUpdated()){
    lastUpdatedFile = currentFile;
  }
 }
}
var ss    =SpreadsheetApp.openById('1W2-83TlLONomkcKtaH6f0Zcm4G9jJ1DdWn9BXBhKo2s'); //      data_sheet_id = id of spreadsheet that holds the data to be updated with new      report data
var sd = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var target = new Array()
var sSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
sheet = SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sSheet.getSheets()[0]);

if ( fi.hasNext()) {
var file = fi.next();
var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());

var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var lastrow = s.getLastRow();
s.getRange(lastrow + 1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
s.getRange(+1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[5].length).setValues(csvData);
}
}
```

Comment: This error is telling you that it can't find the method "hasNext()" within fi (the date)--this is because [getLastUpdated()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getLastUpdated()) returns the Date of the most recent update for the current folder, not the most recently updated file in the folder. If you are looking for CSVs, you will want to [getFilesByType('text/csv')](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfilesbytypemimetype), which will get you to your FileIterator

Comment: Thanks @Altigraph - that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getLastUpdated()), `Folder.getLastUpdated()` returns a Date Object of when the folder was last updated.
So, to iterate over files in a folder you can use `var fi = fSource.getFiles()` which all files in that folder.

And then iterate over them to get the last updated file:

```
var lastUpdatedFile = null;
while(fi.hasNext()){
 if(!lastUpdatedFile){ //Checks if we didn't assign anything to lastUpdatedFile
   lastUpdatedFile = fi.next();
 }else{
  var currentFile = fi.next();
  //lastUpdatedFile is older than the current file
  //set lastUpdatedFile to the current file
  if(lastUpdatedFile.getLastUpdated() < currentFile.getLastUpdated()){
    lastUpdatedFile = currentFile;
  }
 }
}
```

Now `lastUpdatedFile` holds the newest file.

Comment: Thanks @Mahmoud Atwa. It's coming back with a error "Missing ; before statement. (line 5, file "Code")" Have I put your suggestion in the wrong place...I have updated my example above to show where I put it...sorry, still learning.

Comment: @ThomasChristopher My bad, I've used ```let``` instead of ```var``` I've just corrected it.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to have fixed the error, however nothing happens to the input sheet when it runs. Could that be because there is not a new file in the folder today? I have put dummy files in there, however does 'lastupdatedfile" look at time as well as date or stop at date?

Comment: I guess that's because you're using ```fi.hasNext ()``` in the conditional. You can theck if lastUpdatedFiles is not null and then use it as your file without calling ```fi.next ()```